# Checking hard disk memory before file writes

Tags: c

I have a program which simulates the orbits of planets. The information for each time step is written to a `.txt` file with each iteration requiring 64 bytes of memory (8 `doubles`). The time step is chosen by the user and the final time is chosen by the user. This allows me to calculate the amount of memory required on the disk. E.g, a step of 10 with a final time of 1000 gives 100 set of info, implying at least 6400 bytes of memory.

Is there a way of using this information to, for lack of a better word, check the drive to see if there is enough space before allowing the program write to the file, as i would like to prevent files which are too large from being written to disk.  Ideally this should be standard C if possible.

Comment: No it's not possible using only standard C, you need to use operating system specific system calls.

Comment: @nicomp may you please expand on how to do this, or link a source which can explain?

Comment: You could preallocate the file with enough size, and overwrite it, starting at the begin-of-file..

Comment: By the way, are you working on some kind of embedded system with ver small disk, or is the numbers you mentions just examples, the actual size of the data will be much larger (like in the multi-gigabyte range)? Or are you expecting to create several thousands of files?

Comment: Multi-gigabyte range, as an example a simulation of Halley's comet over two years required ~4 GB of space.

Comment: @Hobojoe: Note the word **operating system specific**.  Before anyone can tell you how to do this, you will have to state what operating system you are using.  Please add an appropriate tag as well.  (But a Google search for "<my-os> available disk space C" will probably get you the answer faster.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know in advance exactly how much space you need, you can try for all the needed files:

1. [fopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html) the file and fill it with blanks until you reach the exact size you need.
2. [fflush](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fflush.html) the file and check for error.
3. [rewind](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rewind.html) the file pointer to the beginning and overwrite the content with the real data.

In case of error when fflush'ing, [remove](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/remove.html) all files.

When you're finished, fclose the files.

Comment: A note to the OP (and others): Filling the file with "blanks" is actually crucial, it's not enough to just search to a specific position as that might create a so called *sparse* file with "holes". The size of the file will be correct, but the number of actual disk-blocks will not be.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You're right, this is the reason I didn't use a fseek but I forgot to explain why...

Comment: I take it blanks would be `\0` characters? And would this take excessive computation on say 4GB files? Here i would define excessive as of a size similar to that of the rest of the program itself, which for a 4GB file is ~300s CPU time from experimentation.

Comment: @Hobojoe not excessive computation, but excessive IO time, unless you do something dummy and actually `fputc` 4 billion times.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is probably the only way to do it using only standard C.  However, on any real-life system it would be ridiculous; you should use system-specific functions to check the amount of available disk space.

Comment: @Hobojoe The "blank" data could actually be anything, but zeros are a pretty good number as any other. Also, if you write 32-bit value instead of bytes, you suddenly cut the number of loops to write by 75%. Use larger blocks. If you're on a Linux or OSX system, you could easily emulate the time it takes to write the file by using the [`dd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) command. Unless your simulation is hyper-optimized and fast, the initial file-writing will be small anyway.